# Keeping track of development changes on database structure

Tags: sql, database, database-migration, development-environment

I work in a development team using very basic git principles to develop our project. So every feature is developed in a feature branch and gets merged to when ready.

Often it is necessary to make changes to our database, adding tables, altering columns. Sometimes this includes migration needs. (Casting datatypes, etc)

At the moment we simply write a SQL file containing these changes. And the one "bringing the stuff to production" has to keep track which SQL files are already applied and which still needs to be. If migrations need to be applied comments in the sql file tell you that - Frankly it's a mess ;D

Are there any buzzwords, projects, principles which apply to this scenario?

Comment: Very broad question... svn can probably be useful.

Comment: For MS SQL Server we use [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com) products (I do not work for them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across [goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose) which fullfills all my dreams :) You can make "simple" migrations via plain sql files or you can make complex programmatic changes via go.